# Restore mongodb dump from a folder using Docker in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am new on Docker and MongoDb.
I created a container for mongodb using below command

```
sudo docker run -v /data:/data --name my-mongodb -p 4000:27017 --entrypoint=mongod mongo:2.6.6
```

I have a dump in some folder..I want to restore the data..I tried different ways like

```
sudo docker run -it --link mongotest:db 802e18e53eec mongorestore -h db /path/dump
```

But didn't work.

It says :

```
Unable to find image '802e18e53eec:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/802e18e53eec
docker: Error: image library/802e18e53eec:latest not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: also make sure the dump is stored in the volume (the memory you share between the host and the container) or it won't be accessible from the container

Comment: Thanks @Todea your comment was helpful!!

Answer (score 8):

**I figured out how to do it**

> **NOTE: please explain your question briefly. Question is not clear, please specify where you want to mondodump and restore your data - into server database or your ubuntu running computer. If into server from your local database then follow following steps:-**

Here are the instructions

Copy dump folder to server

```
scp -r /local_path/to/dump_folder root@111.222.33.4:/remote/path
```

SSH into server

```
ssh root@111.222.33.4
```

Copy from root of server to inside docker container

```
docker cp dump_folder mongodb:/dump_folder
```

Go into mongodb docker container

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

check if copied folder exists
`ls` (you should see dump_folder, if you named it the same folder as in this example)

use mongorestore

```
mongorestore --drop -d AppName dump_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to use [`exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) in order to run your command in desired container! `run` creates a new container from an **image**!

Answer (score 1):

You can easy create dump and get it from the container with MongoDB and restore it back without connect to the container

```
docker run --rm mongo:4.1 mongodump --host [container_ip] --archive --gzip | cat > dump_$(date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S').gz
```

and you can simply restore it

```
cat [name_of_dump_file] | docker run --rm -i mongo:4.1 mongorestore --host [container_ip] --archive --drop --db=test
```